# Do networkx have some xml or json encoder/decoder?

Tags: networkx, jsnetworkx

Isn't there any built in function to convert a networkx graph object to an xml/json string and viceversa?

Answer (score 1):

Try http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/readwrite.graphml.html for GraphML
and
http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/readwrite.json_graph.html
for some JSON formats.